# How to plot standard deviation in Advance Design System (ADS) software?

Tags: simulation, standard, s-parameters, ads

I have measured several sets of data using a Vector Network Analyzer, and my data is in S-parameters format. How can I draw a standard deviation plot in ADS software based on my data?